# C2DM sends messages slowly

Tags: java, android, push, android-c2dm

I'm using C2DM in my application, and it works well, but sometimes, when I'm sending lots of messages, the delay is appearing, in it is up to 5 minutes.

All of my messages have the same collape key. Is it normal for C2DM?

**EDIT**: I'm sending approximately 1-2 messages per second

**EDIT2**: It is slow only for one device; another device receives notifications instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is slow only for one device; another device receives notifications instantly

Probably due to network lags, you have to take network transience into account.

By the way, if you are sending 2 messages per second, your are sending 172800 messages to one device per day. You have a limit of 200,000 messages per day for *one C2DM account.* Clearly you aren't using C2DM the way it's *supposed* to be used.  :)

Keep the application state in the server, not in the device, using a collapse key. So that only the most fresh result is delivered. Or else [attenuation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=PLM4LajwDVc#t=1676s) will be used to save battery.

Comment: This problem appears even in emulators with good internet connections. It looks like some queue in C2DM side is full of messages. And, 2 messages in second is for testing, it lasts only 2-3 minutes. Usual count for one device is 5 messages in 30 minutes

Comment: Yes, queues are used. You need to [watch this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=PLM4LajwDVc#t=703s) to understand the various intricacies.

Comment: @Reno How do you know the 200,000 messages/day/account. Are your quoting from some official source?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as Reno linked to:

There is a attenuation. One post on Google Group suggest that each device has 20 tokens, and a new token is created every three minutes. So when you hit the limit, it'll take 3 minutes before you get the next token, thus the delay.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-c2dm/gY2RZBoFth4